# PHP pegar o valor de um select e input sempre que esses forem alterados e consultar MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis

Tenho um campo input que é uma data que altera de acordo com a data escolhida no calendario e 2 selects que são horario de inicio e fim:

```
<input type="text" value="13-08-2017" name="pickdate">

<select id="inicio">
<option value="8">8:00</option>
<option value="9">9:00</option>
</select>

<select id="fim">
<option value="8">10:00</option>
<option value="9">11:00</option>
</select>
```

Com esses dados (data, inicio e fim) o php faz uma consulta no mysql para trazer prestadores de serviço disponiveis nesses horarios.

```
SELECT *
FROM fcs_prestadores_pedidos
WHERE $var_entrada NOT BETWEEN hora_entrada AND hora_saida
AND $var_saida NOT BETWEEN hora_saida AND hora_saida
```

A consulta está pronta e funcionando, minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como fazer para que sempre que o input ou select for alterado, ele refaça a consulta e atualize o resultado?

Comment: Esta usando JQuery?

Comment: Vais precisar de javascript. Se estiver usando JQuery poderá fazer uma consulta via ajax.

Comment: Você fez algo de jQuery já?

Comment: fiz pouco de jQuery, estava usando javascript